# stop spring kafka listener, when there are no records

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a spring kafka listener/consumer group running.
If there are no records(for around, say 5 mins), I want to call an API, which stops that listener and starts another listener.

Answer (score 1):

See a `ListenerContainerIdleEvent` and respective `ContainerProperties.idleEventInterval`:

```
/**
 * Set the idle event interval; when set, an event is emitted if a poll returns
 * no records and this interval has elapsed since a record was returned.
 * @param idleEventInterval the interval.
 * @see #setIdleBeforeDataMultiplier(double)
 */
public void setIdleEventInterval(@Nullable Long idleEventInterval) {
```

The doc is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#idle-containers